# iOS Push Notification - not working in production

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I was able to test push notifications in development but it is not working in production mode. Steps I've done are below:

1. I already had App ID, clicked edit and created certificate under push notifications:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Here is my production Apple Push Service certificate, downloaded it and double clicked it, it showed up in Keychain-> Exported certificate: saved .p12 file:
   [image]
3. Re - downloaded production provisioning profile and double clicked on it. Push notifications are enabled in provisioning profile.
   [image]
4. Changed Entitlement.plist enviroment to production:
   [image]
5. In Visual Studio changed bundle id in Info.plist and set signing Id to distribution and set production provisioning profile. Rebuiled project and uplaoded .IPA file to iTunesConnect and distributed it using TestFlight. 
   Not getting any push notifications. Please help what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Why did you change bundle id?

Comment: We use different bundle ids for dev, prod and staging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Apple Push Service .p12 certificate in the Notification provider also.

Comment: Thank you!!! I had to change my WebConfig file to point to prod certificate and change ApnsEnvironment to productions. :)